# Error while fetching data from a db

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table, `c_question` in which I stored some questions with this structure

```
autoincrement column _id,   
question,  
option1,  
option2,  
option3,  
correct_answer
```

Now I want to retrieve the question in a TextView and the answers in a RadioGroup.
If the user selects the correct answer, then the question and options will change 
in the same page.

> Logcat: fatal exception at main ..... cursorIndexOutOfBoundException

The output shows the last data (question with answers) I entered in the db and if I click any answer, the app crashes.

```
        String row="SELECT* FROM c_question";
        final Cursor c=db.rawQuery(row, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        if(c.moveToFirst())

        {
    do
    {
        tv1.setText(c.getString(1));
        r0=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        r0.setText(c.getString(2));
        r1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        r1.setText(c.getString(3));
        r2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        r2.setText(c.getString(4));

    k.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int idd=r.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            r0=(RadioButton)findViewById(idd);
            String r=r0.getText().toString();
            if(r.equals(c.getString(5)))
            {
                Toast.makeText(QuestionsOn.this, "correct!!!", 123).show();
                ;

        }   else
            Toast.makeText(QuestionsOn.this, "Incorrect!!!", 123).show();


        }
    });

        } while(c.moveToNext());

        }
```

Comment: Can we get a full stack trace?

Comment: Note: you should only be calling `findViewById` once in onCreate, not repeatedly in an loops

Answer (score 0):

> Output showing the last data(Question with options) I entered in DB

That's what you get when you update the save views *in a loop*; only the last "row" will get shown.

If you want to show a list of data from the database, you need some Adapter class in a ListView / ViewPager

> and if I click any option, the app crashes...

According to the error, `c.getString(5)` doesn't exist, so seems like you didn't create your database with the correct number of columns.

Comment: hey thanks but now im doing it with openhelper... but im getting another issue.. I have edited the question.. please suggest

Comment: An OpenHelper should just touch the database, not call setText in the UI on its own, so I don't think that's the problem . And I can't tell what's wrong with the code without a [mcve]

Comment: You did call `if(cr.moveToFirst())` and got the count of the cursor twice... Why? If you move the cursor back to the first, you must reset the ID to 1